Custom View gets cleared after clicking on 'Advanced Lookup' for Lookup field
I have a lookup field for which I need to filter values based on some condition.
I call a function on Form OnLoad to add Custom View to it which works fine.
var viewId = Xrm.Page.getControl("lookupfield").getDefaultView();

formContext.getControl("lookupfield").addCustomView(viewId, "entityname", "viewname", fetchXML, layoutXML, true);

However when I click on 'Advanced Lookup', click done, and then go back to the form, the custom view clears up and filtering doesn't work.
I also tried addCustomFilter :
    setValues: function(executionContext) {
         var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
         formContext.getControl("attributename").addPreSearch(filterValues);
    },

    filterValues: function() {
        var filter = //the same filter which I use for addCustomView,it works fine
        formContext.getControl("attributeName").addCustomFilter(filter, "entityName");
    }

It fires, doesn't throw any error, but simply doesn't filter the values.
I also tried adding the filterValues function inline but in vain.

Another interesting thing that happens is the issue occurs only for the first case that is opened after refreshing the system. For further cases, this issue doesn't arise.

To filter the results of a lookup, you should use formContext.getControl("lookupfield").addCustomFilter(filter, "entitylogicalname") instead.
The filter parameter should be a fetchXml string of the filter you want to apply to the lookup field results.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/controls/addcustomfilter

What happens when user clicks on Advanced Lookup in this case?

I tried using addCustomFilter but it simply doesn't work. The function fires, no errors are thrown but it doesn't filter.

Usually when opening a lookup after adding a custom filter, the search is empty, but when pressing enter in the search field (so searching with an empty search field) the filtered values should appear. Pressing advanced lookup still respects the filter.
Can you post the code you tried? I am using this function right now succesfully.

Also, did you add the PreSearch? This is not optional.

Yes. I have updated the question with addCustomFilter approach as well.
